# Incorporate MathJax onto Weebly website

Tags: javascript, mathjax, weebly, html-head

I run a weebly.com website.

Following instructions to incorporate MathJax, http://www.dessci.com/en/support/MathType/works_with.asp#!target=weebly

First step I completed, i.e. copy and paste

`<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>`

on all page layouts, just before `</head>`

Next set of instructions are unclear, i.e.

> From MathType's Preferences menu choose: Cut and Copy Preferences.
>   From the Equation for application or website group, choose MathJax:
>   LaTeX from the list. Click OK.

Where do I find "MathType's Preferences menu"?

Thank you

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

Researched some more.

Solved it with placing the following on each header page, before `</head>`

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
                       displayMath: [['\\[','\\]'], ['$$','$$']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.